# Tesseract multiple file confusion C++

Tags: c++, tesseract

I am trying to compile the Tesseract OCR code and have run into many problems.  One is that the tessembeded.cpp function calls the "edges_and_textord" function and that other .cpp files call the "find_components" function.  The "edges_and_textord" function is in the textord.cpp file that I downloaded from google, but the "find_components" function is not.  However when I searched google for "textord.cpp" I found a completely different version of "textord.cpp" ([here](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/source/browse/trunk/textord/tordmain.cpp?r=301)) with the "find_components" function in it.  They both have identical commented header information at the very begining of the file (down to the date and time they were created).

So my question is, which one do I use?  The tesseract code calls both of these functions so should I add the second "textord.cpp" file in under a different name?

Comment: Please review your other questions and accept the answers that solved them (if there are any).

Comment: Took care of that.  Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same problem with the "start_recog" function.  The definition I have in my tface.cpp file is

"int Wordrec::start_recog(const char *textbase)"
 but I have found another version of the file on Tesseract's website with the definition

"int start_recog(const char *configfile, const char *textbase)"
And tessembedded.cpp seems to call it using the second definition not found in the code I downloaded.  Should I just replace what I downloaded with the second file?

Why are there these double files in the Tesseract code?